# How do I redirect to page after form submitting?

Tags: .net

I have razor page html form.

To Api, How Do I redirect after from submitting.

```
@page
@model Maqta.Pages.EditEmployeeModel
@{
}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Maqta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Maqta.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Index1" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index1">Maqta</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            <h1>Edit Employee</h1>
            <form method="post"   action="@Model.editUrl">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">id</label>
                    <input type="number" value="@Model.Employee.id" class="form-control" name="id" id="id" placeholder="Enter id">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@Model.Employee.name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" value="@Model.Employee.email" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Mobile</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@Model.Employee.email" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>
                <br />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">A</button>
            </form>
        </main>
    </div>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my API controller,

```
[Route("[action]")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit([FromForm] dynamic obj)
        {
            var returnUrl = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build().GetSection("AppSettings")["BaseUrlWeb"] +
               "Index";
            var dtoModel = new DTO.Employee();
            var id = int.Parse(Request.Form["id"]);
            var firstName = Request.Form["name"];
            var email = Request.Form["email"];
            var mobile = Request.Form["mobile"];
            var entity = unitOfWork.Employee.Get(id);
            unitOfWork.Clear();
            if (entity != null)
            {
                entity.FirstName = firstName;
                entity.Email = email;
                entity.Mobile = mobile;
                entity.Bank = new Entity.EmployeeBank();
                entity.Bank.EmployeeId = id.ToString();
                entity.Bank.Iban = "";
                entity.Bank.IsActive = false;
                entity.Bank.DeletedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                entity.Bank.DeleteUserID = -1;
                entity.Bank.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                entity.Bank.CreationUserID = -1;
                entity.Bank.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                entity.Bank.IsDeleted = false;
                entity.Bank.DeletedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                entity.Bank.Name = "";
                entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                entity.ModifyUserID = 2;
                dtoModel = _mapper.Map<DTO.Employee>(entity);
                dtoModel.EmployeeId = id.ToString();
                unitOfWork.Employee.Update(entity);
                unitOfWork.Complete();
                unitOfWork.Clear();
                return RedirectToPage(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(new
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "ID is not valid"
                }
                );
            }
        }
```

I want to redirect to Url can I do it witouth AJAX ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @user123456,how do  you want to redirect to url, with or without ajax? If you want to redirect without ajax, what you did should work fine. But you need make sure your url is correct. What's the error message you meet from now on?

Comment: @Rena I am getting InvalidOperationException: The relative page path 'returnUrl' can only be used while executing a Razor Page.

Comment: @Rena return Redirect(returnUrl); solved it.